# Help with jquery datepicker calendar date disabling

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

I'm hoping to get some help with my problem i have been having with jquery datepicker.

Please visit this site for information regarding the problem with code samples:
http://codingforums.com/showthread.php?p=929427

Basically, i am trying to get the 1st day and day 31st working and have yet to find a way to do this. They say it may be an error within the jquery calendar.

Here is the code.

```
 //var disabledDays = ['3-31-2010', '3-30-2010', '3-29-2010', '3-28-2010', '3-2-2010', '3-1-2010', '4-1-2010' ];
```

var checkDays = null;

function noWeekendsOrHolidays(date) 
   {
    // optional: ensure that date is date-only, with no time part:
    date = new Date( date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth(), date.getDate() );

```
// no point in checking if today is past the given data:
if ( (new Date()).getTime() > date.getTime() ) return [false,'inthepast'];

if ( checkDays == null )
{
 checkDays = [];
 // convert disabledDays to a more reasonable JS form:
 for ( var d = 0; d < disabledDays.length; ++d )
 {
  var p = disabledDays[d].split("-");
  checkDays[d] = new Date( parseInt(p[2]), parseInt(p[0])-1, parseInt(p[1]) );
 }
}

var datetime = date.getTime();
for ( var i = 0; i < checkDays.length; i++) 
{
 if ( checkDays[i].getTime() == datetime ) return [false,'holiday'];
}
return [true,'']; // default CSS style when date is selectable
```

}

```
 jQuery(document).ready(function() {
<%
response.write "var theSelectedDay = $.datepicker.parseDate(""y-m-d"", '" & theDate & "');" & vbcr
%>

jQuery('#datepicker2').datepicker({
 dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
 constrainInput: true,
 firstDay: 1,
 defaultDate: theSelectedDay,
 beforeShowDay: noWeekendsOrHolidays,
 onSelect: function(date) {
  endDate = date;
  startDate = theSelectedDay;
 }
});
```

});

The theSelectedDay is formatted like ['2010-3-1']

I have set the clock back on my computer in order to test this out. It's set on March 1st.

I have a big calendar on the main page and when the user clicks on a day it pops up this datepicker. Like i said, it all works fine for days 2-30 but not for day 1 and 31.

If they choose day 2 (and it was march 2nd) then Monday would not be selectable of course since its a past day.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

You mean `valueOf()`, not `getTime()`.

Comment: I've changed them to valueOF but it did not make any difference. Still is disabling the 1st day.